# Editing the details in sandbox

Tags: paypal-sandbox

Is it possible to edit the details of the buyers who sent payments like recurring payment in the sandbox.paypal.com.I want to edit the date when they send payments and also when they will expire.

Many Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) to make changes to the profile.

Comment: Hi PP_MTS_Chad, can i ask how can i use those fields?,do i need to put them in my subscription button ?can you give me example like this field ->PROFILESTARTDATE,by the way why there is no PROFILEENDDATE feild?..thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify are you talking about subscriptions or recurring payments?  You have mentioned both, and they are slightly different.

Comment: HI PP_MTS_Chad, that's also should i want to know,because i just created and generated subscription button in the sandbox...as far as i know that i am using subscription...i really don't know why it is recurring payment even there is no choices  on recurring payment when i created the button...I apologize i am confuse...I also really don't know the difference between the two of them.

Comment: This is how i created subscirption button..1)Choose a button type->sbuscription.2)currency->USD.3)Billing amount each cycle->1 year.4)After how many cycles should billing stop?->Never.5)select->Use my secure merchant account ID.6)uncheck->save button to paypal.7) 3: Customize advanced features (optional)->i filled those url like cancel and success and i check add advance variables->modify="1"...that how i created the subscription button,now please tell is that recurring payment i created or subscription?

Comment: Since you are using a subscription rather than a recurring payment you wouldn't be able to set a start date.  This would only work for recurring payments.  You would have to create a modify button if you are wanting to allow the buyers to modify the terms of their existing subscription.  You wouldn't be able to do this for them.

Comment: HI PP_MTS_Chad,Okay if i am in the subscription,can i ask why in the type it is marked as "Recurring payment from" please see my  [screenshot](http://img.sharepixon.net/?v=capturcoc.png).I am just confuse on this.if i will click the link "subscription" and query the date there is no result in subscription...please enlighten my mind.